# Using JRails on Appengine - Gotchas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-app-engine, jrails

Is it possible to run JRails application over Appengine? Is there any experience/gotchas to be considered?

Or is there anyother way to run Rails application over appengine? Now Appengine also supports Google Cloud SQL, so the applications can use RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be confusing [jrails](https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) (a once ubiquitous, but now defunct gem for inserting jquery into your app) and jruby, which [is known to work](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/) on appengine